# Does InnoSetup support the ExpandConstant function in included files?

Tags: inno-setup

The following function used to work well when defined in the main setup script file:

```
function PrevInstallExists: Boolean;
var
  Value: string;
  UninstallKey: string;
begin
  UninstallKey := 'Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Uninstall\' +
    ExpandConstant('{#SetupSetting("AppId")}') + '_is1';
  //MsgBox(UninstallKey, mbConfirmation, MB_OK);
  Result := (RegQueryStringValue(HKLM, UninstallKey, 'UninstallString', Value) or
    RegQueryStringValue(HKCU, UninstallKey, 'UninstallString', Value)) and (Value <> '');
end;
```

But it fails when moved to an included file with this:

```
#include "scripts\util-code.iss"
```

When uncommenting the MsgBox line you'll see that the `ExpandConstant` function returns nothing. I assume that it's because `AppId` is defined in the main script file and not in the included file. Is there a solution to this, other than moving the `ExpandConstant` call outside of this util function and have it passed as parameter?

Comment: Except including the file after the `AppId` directive is defined I don't think so.

Comment: That's it, I had included it near the top of the file. Moving it down above my main Code section works fine now!

Comment: That's because preprocessor doesn't care about your script correctness. It just goes "from top to bottom", sticks files together and evaluates variables. Since you've included the file before the `AppId` directive, it was empty at that time. It got value after your included file was processed.

Comment: Note that `{#...}` values are expanded at compile time, so you do not need to use `ExpandConstant` on them unless they internally contain runtime constants.  For the AppId, this is typically only the case when you are using a GUID and you have doubled the initial `{` as a result.

Comment: Yes, my AppId is a GUID, and I remember that I did have problems with that in the past. Should I not use a GUID there? I think most applications do. But that's probably a new question.